# I am using crud technique in Laravel, and having trouble in editing and deleting data from multi table through one form

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I am having this error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$id

Code:

```
$info = DB::table('info')
    ->join('projectdetails', 'info.id', '=', 'projectdetails.project_id')
    ->select('info.*', 'projectdetails.*')
    ->where('info.id',$id);
    //dd($info);
    return view('info.edit', compact('info'));
```

edit.blade.php

```
<form action="{{route('info.update',$info->id)}}" method="post">
```

Comment: add your whole update method code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $info is a Query Builder object, please try:

```
->where('info.id',$id)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing parameters to the route is done with the following syntax:

```
{{ route('info.update', ['id' => $info->id]) }}
```

Second to this, your controller should expect to receive the `$id`:

```
public function method(Request $request, $id)
{

    // logic
}
```

Last, you must make sure that your route is expecting the `id` by using the `{id}` option within your route helper. An example would be:

```
Route::get('model/{id}', 'ModelController@store');
```

I hope this helps.